# Android Tokbox Swaping video view according to user audio level

Tags: android, kotlin, opentok, tokbox, videocall

I am developing video call ( conference ) app, in that, i want to swap view based on user audio level, means if i have total 5 user in conference then who ever is speaking, that need to be in middle of view, means middle view swap with other view based on higher audio level. ( conference call is working fine but i just issue with swaping view )

My issue is,

In My xml having three row,

First row contain three subscribe view

Second row ( Middle and large ) contain publisher view

Third row contain two subscribe view.

Means total 5 subscriber and one middle publisher.

I set subscribe view as below :

```
    val container = findFirstEmptyContainer()
    if (container == null) {
        Toast.showLongToast(context, "New subscriber ignored. MAX_NUM_SUBSCRIBERS limit reached.")
        return
    }

    container.subscriber = subscriber
    container.container.addView(subscriber.view)
    container.txtName.text = name
    subscriber.setStyle(BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_SCALE, BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FILL)
```

findFirstEmptyContainer()  method used to fill view whatever is empty of of 5 view.
currently i am adding view as in sequence of empty view.

For publisher,

```
     mPublisher = Publisher.Builder(this@VideoChatActivity).name(Prefs.getString(context, PrefsKey.BASIC_INFO_FIRST_NAME, "")).build()
     mPublisher?.setPublisherListener(this@VideoChatActivity)
     mPublisher?.setStyle(BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_SCALE, BaseVideoRenderer.STYLE_VIDEO_FILL)
     publisherView?.addView(mPublisher?.view)
     mSession?.publish(mPublisher)
```

Now, i add setAudioLevelListener of both publisher and subscriber like below,

```
    mPublisher?.setAudioLevelListener(object : PublisherKit.AudioLevelListener {
            override fun onAudioLevelUpdated(p0: PublisherKit?, p1: Float) {

                publisherAudioLevel = p1.toDouble()

            }
        })
```

And,

```
    subscriber.setAudioLevelListener(object : SubscriberKit.AudioLevelListener {
        override fun onAudioLevelUpdated(p0: SubscriberKit?, p1: Float) {

            subscriberAudioLevel = p1.toDouble()
            subscriberViewShow = p0!!.stream    ( Adding stream of subscriber )
        }

    })
```

Now, i am comparing audio level of subscriber and publisher like below,

```
   if (subscriberViewShow != null) {
         if (subscriberAudioLevel > publisherAudioLevel) {
                val subscriberInn = Subscriber.Builder(this@VideoChatActivity, subscriberViewShow).build()

                publisherView.removeAllViews()
                publisherView?.addView(subscriberInn.view)
                mSession?.publish(mPublisher)
            }
        }
```

i am remove all publisher view and then add subscriber view like
publisherView?.addView(subscriberInn.view) that is getting from the subscriber setAudioLevelListener ,

but after adding this view, my publisher view show black, So, I am stuck here,
I get view and replace view with subscriber based on audio level, what going wrong here,
if any one help here then it is very appreciated.